# how do I print on new line in Dash application

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I have created a dash app onto which I have to print the latest values from a database. when retrieving the data it comes out as a list of tuples so I have to format it to print the data separated by a new line. I was unable to achieve it right now through my code. so any suggestions will be of great help. Thanks in advance.

The following is the flow

I receive data as a list of tuples
`[(2.27085, 2.73255,1.0),(2.27085, 2.73255,2.0),(2.27085, 2.73255,3.0)]`
I have labels for each value in the tuple
`['value1', 'value2', 'SNO']`

I am combining them to make a dictionary which will result in something like this
`"{'value1': 2.27085, 'value2': 2.73255, 'SNO': 1.0}`

then I am converting the dictionary into a string to remove the { } from it.

then I am concatenating all strings together by adding a new line at end of every string along with a timestamp so when I print onto the app it should look like this

```
21:40:41

'value1': 2.27085, 'value2': 2.73255, 'SNO': 1.0

'value1': 2.27085, 'value2': 2.73255, 'SNO': 2.0

'value1': 2.27085, 'value2': 2.73255, 'SNO': 3.0
```

instead, I get this on my dash app

```
21:51:12
'value1': 2.27085, 'value2': 2.73255, 'SNO': 1.0Br(None)'value1': 2.27085, 'value2': 2.73255, 'SNO': 2.0Br(None)'value1': 2.27085, 'value2': 2.73255, 'SNO': 3.0Br(None)
```

here is the code I tried

```
import datetime
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
from app import app

printing = html.P(['CONSOLE', html.Br()])

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div([
        dcc.Interval(id="interval", interval=0.9 * 1000, n_intervals=0),
        html.Div(id="content"),
    ])
])


def flask_logger():
    log_mssg = ''
    values = [(2.27085, 2.73255, 1.0), (2.27085, 2.73255, 2.0), (2.27085, 2.73255, 3.0)]
    col_name_list = ['value1', 'value2', 'SNO']
    current_time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')
    if (values is not None and len(values) != 0) and (col_name_list is not None and len(col_name_list) != 0):
        for i in values:
            #concatenate the strings together with a new line at the end
            log_mssg = log_mssg+str(dict(zip(col_name_list, i)))+str(html.Br())
            log_mssg = log_mssg.replace('{', '')
            log_mssg = log_mssg.replace('}', '')
        current_time = [current_time] + [html.Br()] + [log_mssg]
        #print(current_time)
        return current_time
    return 'none'


@app.callback(
    Output("content", "children"),
    Input("interval", "n_intervals"),
    State("content", "children"),
)
def update_output(interval, content):
    if not content:
        return ['']
    x = flask_logger()
    return content + x + [html.Br()]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

FYI I removed the database part and added some data to mimic the action so anyone can run the code directly.

Comment: Can I use JSON format here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever I want to return an iterable with each item on a separate line, I use `html.P()`. So you could rewrite your `flask_logger` function to use:

```py
...
    if (values is not None and len(values) != 0) and (col_name_list is not None and len(col_name_list) != 0):
        log_mssg = [html.P(log_mssg + str(dict(zip(col_name_list, i))).replace('{', '').replace('}', '')) for i in values]
        current_time = [html.P(current_time)] + log_mssg
...
```

Comment: This totally works but I am getting an error after running the script for some time it says    ```dash_renderer.v1_9_1…140379.dev.js:93348 POST http://127.0.0.1:8050/_dash-update-component net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT``` and also this verbose `[Violation] 'setInterval' handler took 350ms` any idea why this happens

Comment: I'm not sure, but it's something to do with your dcc.Interval component. Perhaps the documentation at https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/interval will be helpful. If not, then maybe it's just something to do with your local host timing out for some reason. If you can deploy it and test it there, we might learn more.